# Get it together.

Tags: discussion

A. [Android/EVO bike mount recommendations](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/evo-bike-mount-recommendations)

B. [iPhone 4 bike mount recommendations](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/725/iphone-4-bike-mount-recommendations)

More or less the exact question. Different product.

Comment: Since there's no real consensus at the moment, I'd suggest we leave these questions alone for now.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar questions, but not exact duplicates and answers to one are likely to not be useful for answers to the other. In particular, there's a lot of stuff specifically made for the different iPhones.

However, they are each awfully specific.

It's okay to have similar questions on the site.

Comment: Agreed. Also see [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 3):

What's your point? If I have an iPhone, I don't want to trawl through Android recommendations. The accepted answer in one case will have no bearing on that of the other.

Answer (score 2):

I was only remarking on the potential. One can ask the same basic question on...

- Droid
- DroidX
- RIM Blackberry
- Nexus S
- Or any of the new and upcoming smartphones

So, just asking. It's ok to ask about bicycle smartphone mounts for each and every smartphone?

Anyway I'd suggest adding a tag. "smartphone_mounts"

Comment: I've created the tag: [smartphone-mount](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone-mount)

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem, provided there is a link somewhere between the two, so they show up in the "link questions" bar on the right.   A "see also" comment is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. 4 months of sketchy employment. Sucked to say the least.